# Lightning Web Component Config File

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

Is it possible to organize the config properties in a similar way as the Community standard components? How can we use sliders in the config file? I was not able to find this info in the documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The custom property editors can help achieve this but this is currently are only possible for LWC screen components used in a flow but not for LWC used pages or communities. I guess it should be on the roadmap.

> Without a custom property editor, when an admin configures a custom
> flow screen component or invocable action in Flow Builder, the UI is
> composed of text boxes or combo boxes for the component’s input
> values. The UI of a custom property editor can be composed of any
> input component and can use custom styling.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor_action_example